# Iterating through data frame to buy or reject stocks

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have created the following dummy data for (1 year of stock prices)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(100,200, size = (365,1)), index=list_dates, columns=list('A'))
df.head()
```

Following is the head from the data frame.

```
                A
2018-01-01  151.034052
2018-01-02  157.682393
2018-01-03  134.194843
2018-01-04  199.916593
2018-01-05  194.399690
```

I am trying to compare the price of today and the day before (If stock prices are less than yesterday, "Buy it" otherwise "Don't buy it". I am trying to use "shift" function to check the difference.

```
df['difference'] = df['A'] - df['A'].shift(1)
```

How do I compare the price of the current day to the day before and create a column as "decision" to buy/don't buy the stock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `diff` and `np.where`

```
df['decision'] = np.where(df.A.diff().ge(0), 'buy', 'sell')
```